# SettingWithCopyWarning even when using .loc

Tags: python, pandas

Why am i getting SettingWithCopyWarning in this code? I know that when defining a new Dataframe, i need to use .copy(), but that doesn't help.

```
   def calc_quantity(input_df):
        when = input_df['SecurityId'].str.endswith(
            'TMS') | input_df['SecurityId'].str.endswith('TDS')
        input_df['Quantity'] = input_df['Quantity'].fillna(0).astype(float)
        input_df['Quantity'].loc[when] *= 100
            'TMS') | input_df['SecurityId'].str.endswith('TDS').copy()
        input_df['Quantity'] = input_df['Quantity'].fillna(0).astype(float).copy()
        input_df['Quantity'].loc[when] = input_df['Quantity'].loc[when]*100
        return input_df['Quantity']
```

Comment: This is because `input_df` is already subselection of the original dataframe. So wherever you filter input_df, you need to add `.copy`

Comment: I've changed to  ```def calc_quantity(input_df):
                                   when = input_df['SecurityId'].str.endswith(
                                            'TMS') | input_df['SecurityId'].str.endswith('TDS').copy()
                                   input_df['Quantity'] = 
                                   input_df['Quantity'].fillna(0).astype(float).copy()
                                   input_df['Quantity'].loc[when] = 
                                 input_df['Quantity'].loc[when].copy()*100    return input_df['Quantity']  ```          but got some warning

Comment: put it in question - it will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: put it in question-Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning typically is a result of chained assignments and you can read more about it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/13330692) and this [blog post](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) also goes into great detail.

If you wish to turn it off, you can use:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```